# search multiple ids in multiple types in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I want to fetch documents with ids in specific type. For example right now I have wrote this query in Sense. This query is returning me all the documents with these ids in type product.

```
  POST /_search
    {
        "query": {
           "ids" :{
              "type" : "product",
              "values" : ["100005","10002010093"]
         }
      }
    }
```

But what I want here is something like this

```
 POST /_search
        {
            "query": [
             {
               "ids" :{
                  "type" : "product",
                  "values" : ["100005","10002010093"]
             }
             },
             {
               "ids" :{
                  "type" : "store",
                  "values" : ["100003","1000201"]
             }
             }
         ]
        }
```

or

```
 POST /_search
        {
            "query":{
                "ids" :[
                  {
                     "type" : "product",
                     "values" : ["100005","10002010093"]
                  },
                  {
                     "type" : "store",
                     "values" : ["100003","1000201"]
                  }
               ]
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to get it done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply need to use the [`bool/filter` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
POST /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "type": "product",
            "values": [
              "100005",
              "10002010093"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "ids": {
            "type": "store",
            "values": [
              "100003",
              "1000201"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working, it is returning this response.
 `{
   "took": 13,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 25,
      "successful": 25,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}`

And I am sure that the ids I have provided exist.

Comment: My bad, you need to use `should` not `filter`, please try again.